# How to move the light source position while in the Shading tab

Tags: lighting

In the *Shading* tab, I'd like to move the position of the spot lighting source.

I cannot drag it into a new position if I left-click it and drag it.

[image: How to move the light source position while in the Shading tab]

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why it's always good to learn the shortcuts... simply press <kbd>G</kbd> and move the light wherever you need it.

If you want to constrain the movement to a certain axis, let's say X, just press the corresponding key afterwards: <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

And if you want to move it a specific distance like 1.5 m on X, enter the values after the tool and axis keys: <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

Then left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the translation.

If you explicitly need the *Move* tool with its gizmo to do this, just enable the toolbar either by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> in the *3D Viewport* or from the menu *View* > *Toolbar* and then choose the *Move* tool:

[image: toolbar]